# How to count variables in duplicates in R

Tags: r

I want to count variables in duplicates.
I used this code.

```
library(dplyr)
mydata2<-mydata %>%group_by(sub) %>%summarise(n = n())
mydata2
```

But, you know, in this code, it counts A and A,B differently.
But I want to get numbers' of variables as A to 3, B to 3, C to 2 from the below data.
How can i make code for it?

Here is my data.

```
num                                           sub
1                                              A  
2                                             A,B 
3                                              C            
4                                              A    
5                                              B     
6                                              B,C
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydata %>% 
     separate_rows(sub) %>% 
     count(sub)
```

Comment: Does this apply to other text messages such as Korean?

Comment: @JayChoi this applies to any dataset similar to the one you presented.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R` with `strsplit` and `table`

```
table(strsplit(mydata$sub, ","))
```

Comment: I got the message of error that all of argument must have same length. Cuz the data I posted were sample and I want to apply other data.

Comment: @JayChoi It should work if you are applying this on a single column